# How to invoke BlackBerry Traffic from another application?

Tags: java, blackberry, invoke

I've found many examples on how to invoke applications from within your application. I surfed stackoverflow first to see if there were similar questions and there are, just not as specific as mine.

Is there a way to invoke the **Blackberry Traffic Application** *AND* pass it arguments like all the other methods I have been seeing so far?(Methods I've seen posted below).
What arguments would it expect? Lat, Lng? A mapview of some sort?
I'm really not sure.

Current this is the method I am using for Google Maps Application invocation: 
Works very well:

http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/143263-heres-how-start-google-maps-landmark.html

and this is the method I am using for Blackberry Maps: (I know I can use the method above as well):

```
public void invokeBlackBerryMaps(double lat, double lng, AddressInfo addressInfo, String address)
{
    Landmark []landmarks = new Landmark[1];
    // PinPointing the exact location with lat,lng
    QualifiedCoordinates coordinates = new QualifiedCoordinates(lat, lng, 0, 0, 0);

    landmarks[0] = new Landmark(address,address,coordinates,addressInfo);
    MapsArguments mapsArgs = new MapsArguments(landmarks);
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS,mapsArgs);
}
```

Any help on this would really be appreciated...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Only blackberry apps you can invoke are as follows,

- address book
- Bluetooth config
- Calculator
- Calender
- Camera
- Maps
- Memo Pad
- Messages
- Phone
- Search
- Tasks

Comment: Could you provide the resource where you found this info?

Answer (score 0):

In My Eclipse, if you type the following `Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.` and then press CTRL+ space then it gives you all available functions for invoking a bb application.

Answer (score 0):

Core Applications that you can invoke!

https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/invoking_core_apps.html